# iOS share extension : hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier gives wrong type

Tags: swift, flutter, share-extension

I am following this https://github.com/KasemJaffer/receive_sharing_intent/tree/master/example to get share extension for my flutter app. The objective is to share image/video/text from any other app to my app. It works fine in general case. And I am able to get shared media in my app. But the problem is when I kill the app and try to share an image, this below code returns text type instead of image type -

```
if let content = extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem {
            if let contents = content.attachments {
                for (index, attachment) in contents.enumerated() {
                    if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(imageContentType) {
                        handleImages(content: content, attachment: attachment, index: index)
                    } else if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(textContentType) {
                        handleText(content: content, attachment: attachment, index: index)
                    } else if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(urlContentType) {
                        handleUrl(content: content, attachment: attachment, index: index)
                    } else if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(videoContentType) {
                        handleVideos(content: content, attachment: attachment, index: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It works fine for general case but only when I kill my app, it return "text" type for Image. hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier is not working properly. How can I fix this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you to write this in the plugin Github. might bring the creator attention better

Comment: @Karim I already did that, But didn't get any response. And the above code is not related to plugin. hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier method returns wrong response. And this method is apple's predefined function.